# Filter an ArrayList to between two dates

Tags: java, android, date, sorting, arraylist

I have a ArrayList "List"

```
Receipts{
int invoice;
String date;
double amount;
....
}
```

i want to filter the List to between two dates.

```
public List<Receipts> sortListByDate(String date1,String date2,List<Receipts> receipts){

   List<Receipts> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();

  // if receipts.date() is between(or including) date1 and date2 then sortedList.add(that object)

  return sortedList;
}
```

receipt.date() , date1 and date2 are in the format String "dd-MM-yyyy"

Help me to filter (that is, to complete the "sortListByDate" function)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i sort the arraylist to between two dates ?

Comment: Does "sort" actually mean "filter"? Or does it actually need to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stream of `receipts`, you need to filter the elements based on dates (i.e. not before `date1` and not after `date2`), sort the resulting stream, collect it into a `List` and return the same.

**Steps:**

1. Parse the date stings using `DateTimeFormatter`.
2. Create a stream from `receipts` and apply `filter` with the required criteria.
3. Sort the resulting stream.
4. Collect the resulting stream into a `List` and return the same.

**Code:**

```
public List<Receipts> sortListByDate(String date1, String date2, List<Receipts> receipts) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(date1, formatter);
    LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(date2, formatter);

    return receipts.stream()
            .filter(e -> !LocalDate.parse(e.date(), formatter).isBefore(localDate1)
                    && !LocalDate.parse(e.date(), formatter).isAfter(localDate2))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implements Comparable in Receipts class and overRide the compareTo method by any thing you want
and after that just call sort method on your list
see the docs for more information to how to do it:
https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework